# 'import pyPDF2' results in 'ModuleNotFoundError' on windows powershell

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

I'm currently using sublime with windows powershell(terminal). Using the interpreter I'm typing `import PyPDF2` and keep having an error :getting module not found. Even though I do have it installed.

sublime;

```
import PyPDF2 
with open("dummy.pdf", "r") as file:
    print(file)
```

terminal;

```
PS C:\Users\alex\OneDrive\Desktop\pdf_playground> python3 pdf.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alex\OneDrive\Desktop\pdf_playground\pdf.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PyPDF2
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
```

I also verified and that was installed.

```
PS C:\Users\alex\OneDrive\Desktop\pdf_playground> pip3 install PyPDF2
Requirement already satisfied: PyPDF2 in c:\users\alex\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (3.0.1)
```

Comment: Must be a different Python virtual environment. You'll have to verify that they're the same environment.

Answer (score 0):

what ended up working for me was installing

> pip install pypdf

PyPDF2 is no longer being worked on and because of this some of the names have been changed https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/migration-1-to-2.html

```
    import PyPDF2

with open("dummy.pdf", "r") as file:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
    print(reader.numPage)
```